# Using Homebrew with alternate GCC

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I've installed `gcc-4.6` using the `homebrew-alternatives gcc` formula, but I can't seem to get it to use that GCC to install other formulas. Specifically Open-MPI and boost.

Does anyone know how to make Homebrew use this new compiler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These answers are all fairly old now. It seems that recent versions of homebrew have a '--cc' option that enables you to select the c compiler to use. For example

```
brew install --cc=gcc-6 <package-name>
```

will install using the brew version of gcc

Answer (score 21):

It looks like the latest versions of Homebrew now support the `HOMEBREW_CC` and `HOMEBREW_CXX` environment variables.

So now you can do the following:

```
$ HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.2 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.2 brew install ice
```

Comment: Worked for me! `HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.5 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.5 brew install sfcgal`

Comment: why I can't do `HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.9 brew install openmpi`

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of 'authorized' environment variables used by Homebrew? I cannot seem to find it when googling...

Answer (score 20):

Homebrew can't adapt to other versions of gcc using command line options.  You can easily override the older compiler, though, if you edit the open-mpi and boost formula.  For example, you can add a few commands after the "def install" in open-mpi.rb:

```
  def install
    # Force compilation with gcc-4.6
    ENV['CC'] = '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.6'
    ENV['LD'] = '/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.6'
    ENV['CXX'] = '/usr/local/bin/g++-4.6'

    # Compiler complains about link compatibility with FORTRAN otherwise
    ENV.delete('CFLAGS')
    ENV.delete('CXXFLAGS')
```

That worked for me on Lion.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!  That sounds like pretty much exactly what I wanted... I tried to set CC and CXX from the command line, but apparently brew kills the environment.

Answer (score 2):

From [their wiki](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers) it sounds like they don't support other compilers:

> Installing a custom version of GCC or autotools into the $PATH has the potential to break lots of compiles. So we stick to the Apple-provided compilers.