# How to permanently override HOMEBREW_CC and HOMEBREW_CXX settings?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

Since I installed `gcc-49` on my Mac I can't get Homebrew to find the C++ compiler anymore. It always fails with error messages like:

```
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
```

Running "brew upgrade -v" spits out this:

```
...
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: llvm-gcc
HOMEBREW_CXX: llvm-g++
...
```

I have no idea why Homebrew wants to use these compilers. Why can't it use the normal CC/CXX environment variables like everything else?

I already found, that by editing the formula directly like described in [Using Homebrew with alternate GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9186033/608639), I can change the `HOMEBREW_CXX` to use `/usr/local/bin/g++` for example, which makes compiling formulas that need C++ work again.

But I don't want to edit every single formula by hand for the rest of my days. How can I change this `HOMEBREW_CXX` environment variable **permanently**? I tried setting them in my .bash_profile and running "export HOMEBREW_CXX=..." in the console and neither of those work, only editing the formula directly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: any success? I am looking at how to set Homebrew to use GCC by default

Answer (score 5):

A poor man's solution, to be sure, but this works: put an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
alias brew='HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.8 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.8 brew'
```

Now, whenever you use `brew` it will use the compilers you want. Check that it works by doing:

```
brew --env
HOMEBREW_CC: gcc-4.8
HOMEBREW_CXX: g++-4.8
...
```

HTH