# Installing valgrind and/or gdb with brew?

Tags: gdb, valgrind, homebrew

I am having some trouble installing valgrind using brew.  I am using the command:

```
brew install valgrind
```

and getting the error

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.9.0 --enable-only64bit -- build=amd64-darwin
checking for gcc... gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/valgrind-bA4juk/valgrind-3.9.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I get a similar error with gdb

```
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gdb/gdb-7.7.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gdb-7.7.1.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.7.1 --with-system-readline --with-python=/usr
checking for gcc... gcc-4.2
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/gdb-6Ivx9u/gdb-7.7.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues
```

However the C compiler is

```
$ cc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog018 --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl011 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc49 4.9.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.0)
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?  I'm on OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
checking for gcc... gcc-4.2
gcc version 4.9.0 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.0)
```

The output from brew and the manual run is showing 2 separate version of gcc, and brew is picking up the really old one. Set your environment so that `which gcc` returns the 4.9 version.

Comment: When I type 

`which gcc`

I get 

`/usr/bin/gcc`

and when I type `gcc -v` I get 

`gcc version 4.9.0 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.0)`

Is this what you mean? Am I missing something?

Comment: It appears that homebrew is using gcc 4.2 it finds somewhere. What version of brew do you have? Do you have gcc 4.2 installed somewhere?

Comment: I'm using brew 0.9.5 and I think brew install gcc 4.2 when I did `brew install gcc` but I don't know how to remove it...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here

[Using Homebrew with GCC-4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186033/using-homebrew-with-gcc-4-6)

I solved the problem by installing

`HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.9 brew install gdb`

and

`HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.9 brew install valgrind`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this command to install valgrind on Yosemite using brew: brew install --HEAD valgrind at worst you may need to do these set commands prior: HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.5 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.5 brew