# How to build openmpi with homebrew and gcc-4.9?

Tags: gcc, clang, homebrew, openmpi

By default `brew install openmpi` uses `clang` to create its wrapper.

I need to specify `gcc-4.9`(Homebrew installed) for the wrapper.

I have tried

```
$export CC=gcc-4.9
$brew install openmpi

$brew install --cc=gcc-4.9 openmpi

$brew install --with-gcc49 openmpi

$brew install -CC=gcc-4.9 -CXX=g++-4.9 -FC=gfortran -F77=gfortran openmpi

$brew install openmpi --cc=gcc-4.9 

$brew install openmpi --CC=gcc-4.9 --CXX=g++-4.9 --FC=gfortran --F77=gfortran
```

Finally, I've modified the `openmpi` formula adding:

```
 args = %W[
  CC=gcc-4.9 
  CXX=g++-4.9 
  FC=gfortran 
  F77=gfortran
```

I still get

```
$mpicc --showme
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/include -L/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/lib -lmpi
```

Comment: Why don't you just install it from source yourself?

Comment: I want to learn how to set the compiler for other packages too

Comment: My guess is that what you did to modify the homebrew recipe is right and you're just seeing the results of an old installation. At least it looks fine to me.

Comment: If you really wanted to have a long term solution here, you could submit a patch to the homebrew people and add some new flags to give you the option to set your own compiler.

Comment: Yes I think here they gave a similar solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186033/using-homebrew-with-gcc-4-6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally it was solved as follows:

1) Add environment variables for homebrew (you can also add these lines to your `~\.bashrc`):

```
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9
export HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.9
```

2) Rebuild and reinstall `openmpi` and its dependencies from source

```
brew reinstall openmpi --build-from-source
```

3) In the end you will get a message like:

```
==> Reinstalling open-mpi
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.8/downloads/openmpi-1.8.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/open-mpi-1.8.4.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4 --disable-silent-rules 
==> make all
==> make check
==> make install
Warning: open-mpi dependency gcc was built with a different C++ standard
library (libstdc++ from clang). This may cause problems at runtime.
  /usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4: 785 files, 23M, built in 41.2 minutes

$mpicc --showme 
gcc-4.9 -I/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/include -L/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.4/lib -lmpi
```

On my MacBook I had some conflicts with XCode 6.2, which were solved following [this instructions](http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/osx-gcc-dispatch_block_t-has-not-been-declared-invalid-typedef/)

However, I decided to stay with the `clang` version to avoid issues with `gfortran`.

Comment: Why did you decide to stay with clang to avoid issues with gfortran? I do not get this statement.

Comment: @Chiel I used to had issues when building with `openmpi` and `gfortran`, thus building `openmpi` with `clang` inhibitted `gfortran`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, without any issues! And our MPI application runs a *lot* faster (~30%) when using openMPI compiled with GCC instead of openMPI with clang.

Comment: @bart which versions of GCC and openMPI are you using?

Comment: @ilciavo GCC 6.1 with openMPI 1.10.2

Comment: @Bart you're right the issue disappeared with GCC 6.1 but it is still present if you want to build with gcc-4.9

Comment: can you update this answer to current versions?