# Specify compiler Homebrew install

Tags: macos, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, homebrew

I have hit a roadblock when trying to install `mkvtoolnix` with `homebrew` on OSX 10.8

When I try `brew install mkvtoolnix` I get the following error trace

```
checking for support for C++11 feature "nullptr"... yes
checking for support for C++11 feature "tuples"... yes
checking for support for C++11 feature "alias declarations"... yes
checking for support for C++14 feature "std::make_unique"... no
checking for support for C++14 feature "digit separators"... no
checking for support for C++14 feature "binary literals"... no
checking for support for C++14 feature "generic lambdas"... no
The following features of the C++11/C++14 standards are not supported by clang++:
  * std::make_unique function (C++14)
  * digit separators (C++14)
  * binary literals (C++14)
  * generic lambdas (C++14)
If you are using the GNU C compiler collection (gcc) then you need
at least v4.9.x.
configure: error: support for required C++11/C++14 features incomplete
```

Which makes sense since clang++ does not support C++14 features. Moreover, I have installed GCC 5.2 and thus could use `g++-5.2.0` to compile those.

The problem is I have not seen anyway of setting a different compiler when calling `brew install`

I have already tried adding `cc`,`c++`,`gcc` and `g++` to the PATH and symlinking them to `usr/local/bin` and `usr/bin` to no avail, it always resorts to `clang++`

How can I specify `g++-5.2.0` as the compiler?

Comment: Maybe this will be a help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492814/4669978

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an option to your install command:

```
brew install --cc=gcc-5.2 mkvtoolnix
```

Take care that only a restricted list of compilers are allowed (homebrew compilers). You should also check that gcc-5.2 is installed:

```
which gcc-5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

With newer versions of Homebrew, it now supports the use of `HOMEBREW_CC` and `HOMEBREW_CXX` environment variables. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492814/6362595) for details.